# JS equivalent of Python's "with" keyword that automatic cleans up after usage

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

We have lots of JS code with teardown after usage. For instance, in our Jest tests, we setup mocks and spys, which we clear after usage:

```
    const spyApig = jest.spyOn(apig, "postToConnection").mockImplementation(mockPostToConnectionSuccess)
    const spyOnStdout = jest.spyOn(process.stdout, "write")

    // Do some behavior and test that it's as expected
    ...

    // Teardown spies
    spyApig.mockRestore()
    spyOnStdout.mockRestore()
```

In Python, we wouldn't have such teardowns, but instead implement it using the "with" operator, which would clean up the code after usage. Imagining a Python version of JS, it would look along the lines of:

```
    with spyApig = jest.spyOn(apig, "postToConnection").mockImplementation(mockPostToConnectionSuccess):
        with spyOnStdout = jest.spyOn(process.stdout, "write"):
            // Do some behavior and test that it's as expected
            ...
```

Obviously, JS and Python are very different languages. However, is there a way to do something similar in JS to avoid the explicit teardowns everywhere?

Comment: There's no standard way, but since you're using jest https://jestjs.io/docs/en/setup-teardown